# How to reshape input for ConvLSTM2D to not overfit?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, machine-learning-model

I have a time series problem with 15 minutes as a timestep.The complete data will be from 2016-09-01 00:00:15 to 2016-12-31 23:45:00.

I have 5 variables(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6) in the data frame and I want to predict the sixth variable (v6) for the next timestep.

I prepare the data set and prepare the information as 5-time lags. like if the time is **t** in the row I create the values for (t-1) to (t-5) as lags for v1 to v6.

So in total, I have 30 features (5 lags for 6 variables).
I also normalize the values by PowerTransformer.

```
scaler_x = PowerTransformer()
scaler_y = PowerTransformer()
train_X = scaler_x.fit_transform(train_X)
train_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(train_y.reshape(-1,1))
```

My data input shape of traix_X and train_y is like below at initial:

```
(11253, 30) , (11253, 1)
```

11253 rows having 30 variables as input and a single variable as target variable .Then i reshape this to fit my ConvLSTM2D like below:

```
# define the number of subsequences and the length of subsequences
n_steps, n_length = 5, 6 #I take into account of past 5 steps for the 6 variables
n_features=1
#reshape for ConvLSTM
# reshape into subsequences [samples, time steps, rows, cols, channels]
train_X = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0], n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)
train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[1], 1))
```

The ConvLSTM2D architecture looks like below :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(RepeatVector(1))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

But this model gives a very bad result (It is **overfitting** a lot). I suspect that my inputs are not given correctly to the ConvLSTM2D.
Is my reshaping correct?  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have realized my input is being given correctly to the Network but the issue is it is overfitting a lot.
[image]

My hyperparameters are below :

```
#hyper-parameter
epochs=100
batch_size=64
adam_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
```

I even tried 50 and 10 epochs its same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience there are a few things I've picked up about using ConvLSTM2D.

- I would first check to see if the model is training at all. Based on your answer I am unsure how loss is changing as your model trains - if at all. If there is some variation, you need to perform a grid search (playing around with amount of layers and filters)
- I also found my models needed to train for a long time to perform well, see the Keras example on ConvLSTM2d where 300 epochs are needed to train a model to perform an arguably simple task : https://keras.io/examples/conv_lstm/. A case I worked on needed a similar amount of epochs to train.
- Check different loss functions and optimizers (even though I think mse and adam are good for this type of problem)
- Normalize your data differently, you may want to normalize your data statistically as 
  shown in this keras example : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression
- From personal experience, you might want more layers for this specific problem. See keras ConvLSTM2d example above for this
- *** I see how you want to format your data, and though it may work, a more straightforward solution may work better. You might want to try giving (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) and predicting for v6. You may have the use large batch sizes for this. ***

Comment: Thanks george for the inputs.But are my inputs given correctly ?Since  I am new to ConvLSTM2D wanted to check if that is correct ?

Comment: Ricky, your input is given correctly. That being said - see my last bullet point in asterisks. I believe giving your data in this way may be **difficult** to understand (not impossible!) for the network. I would suggest trying my solution with providing inputs of (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) and letting the network predict v6. I would not provide 5 lags as you did, the network might have trouble determining easily the difference between lags.

Comment: Oh ok so you mean sometimes giving lag values of before timesteps will not be easy to the network to understand. I followed the approach from  https://www.kaggle.com/kcostya/lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecast#ConvLSTM-Encoder-Decoder-Model-With-Multivariate-Input  where they do for 2 lags and i do it for 5 lags.

Comment: Exactly. It seems like you have a similiar data structure to what they use in that kaggle example, so that is correct. Without having trained the example myself, I believe your network is performing poorly due to the lack of complexity of your network. Using 5 lags as opposed to 2 as in the example - I believe you will need more parameters in your network.

Comment: I found that the reason for performing poorly is because of the overfitting issue. I have updated the question with more information. I am planning to add dropouts and see first . Any other things that you recommend?

Comment: Ricky, I would also check to see if your data is being properly shuffled, that might be another potential culprit in higher validation loss.

Comment: Oh so I have to add `shuffle=True` while I  fit the model. Because usually I see examples where shuffle=False and thought it should not be used in time series problems.